# Mini LED or diode that can turn on with 220 V

Tags: voltage, led, identification

I have an air conditioner fan that is working with 220 V. That fan has a mini LED or diode that is connecting to 220 V through a terminal. Here is its image:

[image]

What kind of LED or diode can turn on with 220 V without damage? What is the name of that LED for buying it?

Comment: What circuit did this come out of?  It's extremely likely that any additional resistor is already on that circuit.  Can you get a photo of where it was on your air conditioner?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is not a LED.

That is a neon indicator lamp.

Comment: Can that neon lamp turn with 220v on without any damage? That lamp's size is like a diode and in uploaded image you can n't recognize it.

Comment: I asked this Q for prevent any fire on my place after connecting that lamp to fan.

Comment: For connecting it to 220v what kind of resistance should i use?

Comment: Buy a neon bulb rated for 220V.

Comment: Neon bulbs themselves are not rated for 220V or 110V. They may come packaged with a resistor so then the whole assembly is rated for mains voltage, or they may come as bare bulb without a resistor so you need to add a resistor. The exact resistor value depends on which neon bulb you will buy and how bright you want it to be, so better refer to the data sheet of any bulb you intend to buy.

Answer (score 7):

A standard neon lamp should need a resistor of about 330k ohms for 220V.  You can tweak that resistance depending on how bright you want it to be.  220k ohms would be brighter.  1M ohm would glow dimly.

But if you're replacing an existing neon, then there's probably already a resistor somewhere to limit the current.